# AWS: How to load balance multiple VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I have three VPCs, main-vpc, vpc-a and vpc-b on AWS. I created VPC peering.

```
VPC peering:
main-vpc and vpc-a
main-vpc and vpc-b
```

vpc-a has a eks cluster. vpc-b has its eks cluster. Both eks clusters expose the LoadBalancer. I can hit the URLs of vpc-a(eks) and vpc-b(eks). I would like to create a load balancer at main-vpc so that traffic can be directed to vpc-a and vpc-b. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the reason you need to do this?

If the load balancer is private (already having peering there are no problems):
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-access-load-balancer-vpc-peering/

If the load balancer is public you just need to point to the endpoints (they are reachable by other vpc).